# How to draw a string to screen in C# XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, draw

I am attempting to add "Lives: 3" to a platformer game using C#.

Currently the game draws the score in a `Drawhud()` method like this:

```
// Draw time remaining. Uses modulo division to cause blinking when the
            // player is running out of time.
            string timeString = "TIME: " + level.TimeRemaining.Minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + level.TimeRemaining.Seconds.ToString("00");
            Color timeColor;
            if (level.TimeRemaining > WarningTime ||
                level.ReachedExit ||
                (int)level.TimeRemaining.TotalSeconds % 2 == 0)
            {
                timeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                timeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            DrawShadowedString(hudFont, timeString, hudLocation, timeColor);

            // Draw score
            float timeHeight = hudFont.MeasureString(timeString).Y;
            DrawShadowedString(hudFont, "SCORE: " + level.Score.ToString(), hudLocation + new Vector2(0.0f, timeHeight * 1.2f), Color.Yellow);
```

I have attempted to draw the lives like this (have simplified the code alot):

```
// Players lives
        public const int PlayerLives = 3;

// Draw Player Lives
            float LivesHeight = hudFont.MeasureString(timeHeight).Y;
            DrawShadowedString(hudFont, "Lives: " + Player.PlayerLives.ToString("0"), hudLocation + new Vector2(0.0f, LivesHeight * 1.4f), Color.Yellow);
```

This doesn't draw the string i created in the `DrawShadowString()` method. Why is this? and is there a simpler way of doing it?

This is the `DrawShadowedString()` method as requested:

```
private void DrawShadowedString(SpriteFont font, string value, Vector2 position, Color color)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, value, position + new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f), Color.Black);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, value, position, color);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can I see the drawShadowedString method please?

Comment: Can you pin it down to the drawShadowedString method? By just ignoring all the other code and just drawing a string "test" or something?

Comment: @Bushes I have added the method to my question at the bottom, thanks.

Comment: A couple of questions I can think of: 1. I presume it does actually call i.e. you've debugged it? Check that and whilst doing so also check the final position and check it's actually drawing o the screen bounds, not at a position like  X:-100 Y: -100. Don't forget the coordinates used mean that x:0 y:0 is the top left corner.

Comment: Long time since i used XNA, but don't you need a Sprite object aswell for drawing strings? And especially its Begin and End calls?

Comment: @dowhilefor I think what he's done regarding drawing the strings should be correct. All text should use spriteBatch.DrawString to well draw strings!